# Why doesn't this loop process one file at a time?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I've got a directory with various files:

```
main.js
SomeClass.js
View.jsx
```

And I want to loop through all the .jsx files. So I wrote this Bash script:

```
for JSX_FILE in "$BUILD_DIR/*.jsx"; do   
    echo $JSX_FILE
    echo "PATH: $JSX_FILE"
    JSX_FILENAME=$(basename "$JSX_FILE")
    echo "NAME: $JSX_FILENAME"
done
```

But for some reason that would print this:

> /path/to/View.jsx
>
> PATH: /path/to/*.jsx
>
> NAME: *.jsx

So I don't understand why in one case `$JSX_FILE` has the value `/path/to/View.jsx` and in another case it has the value `/path/to/*.jsx`. How can I make sure this variable will have the same value everywhere within the loop?

Comment: what do you think is the difference between `echo $JSX_FILE` and `echo "$JSX_FILE"` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting the glob inhibits globbing.

```
for JSX_FILE in "$BUILD_DIR"/*.jsx; do
```

Comment: Specifically, the asterisk gets passed in to the loop unchanged, and then it's only expanded when the shell runs the echo command.